# Get return url from HttpPost

Tags: android, url, http-post

How can i get return URL from HttpPost. I'm using this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2)
blablabla adding pairs...
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

The page i request redicts me to another one and i want to know it's url

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();?